# 100% window height | 100% parent div width

Tags: css, scroll, height, width

I want to create an HTML page which:

- Appears centred horizontally
- Has a white background the entire height of the window
- Contains a fixed header and scrollable content

I am having two issues related to {width: 100%} and {height: 100%}.

My header is 100% of the page width, when I expect it to be 100% of its parent width.
The background appears at 100% of the window height, but it then scrolls up with the content.

I would appreciate any help in understanding how CSS treats the 100% value in these two cases. I am not asking for a workaround: I already have that. I am asking for insights into the way CSS thinks.

Many thanks in advance,

James

[Here's a demo of the issue](http://dev.lexogram.com/tests/100percent/)

And here's the barebones HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Width & Height 100%</title>

<style>
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0;
}

#header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    background:#ffe;
    /* width:760px; */
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    width:360px;
    height:360px;
    margin:64px 0 0 0;
    background:#efe;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        Fixed header
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        Scrollable content
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your case is not a problem of a misunderstanding the width and height property, your problem is in the positioning of the elements

Answer (score 0):

**Fix header**
Change the header position `fixed` to position `absolute`

**Fix content height**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    background:#efe;
}
#content {
    padding: 64px 20px 0;
}
```

**Live example with pos fixed**
http://jsfiddle.net/qB4sD/1/

Comment: I think you an keep the fixed, if that is what you are after. The key lies in setting the height to auto and the min height to 100%. You should also do this for the body and html. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SQRuB/

Comment: Hi Niels! Many thanks for your input. I have tried incorporating your CSS changes into my project, but I am not sure whether they are additions or replacements. In either case, I failed to get the effect that I wanted. Setting the header position to absolute makes it scroll with the page, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All of these fixed positions are going to give you headaches.

About the widths: the box model is usually the problem.  I start every CSS with body height and width set to 100%, and then reset my box model so it matches across browsers, and applies all of my padding to the inside of a box instead of the outside:

```
/* Set box models to match across browsers. */
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

Then set your width on a container using padding, first the mobile width, then the screen width to override:

```
#container {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
        @media only screen
        and (min-width : 700px) {

            #container {
            padding: 0% 30%;
            }

        }
```

For a full layout, you can visit my site:
http://instancia.net/fluid-sticky-footer-layout/

I should probably add the mobile bit to that page. :)

Comment: are you not over complicating things here? And what about legacy browsers that do not support the border-box or the media queries?